# Code for Alternating 2 Box Pattern using if statements

Tags: c#

I am trying to find a code that helps to create a pattern of:

[image: Picture of Checkered 2box pattern]

but the number of rows and columns are custom.
Currently this is the code I have but it doesnt apply properly for all values.

(labelseat.backcolour=color.red , refers to the red boxes)

```
count=0;
if (Row%2==0)
{
     count+=1;

     if (count==3)
     {
          labelSeat.BackColor=Color.Red;
     }
     else if (count==4)
     {
          labelSeat.BackColor=Color.Red;
          count=0;
     }

}
     
if (Row%2==1)
{
     count+=1;

     if (count==1)
     {
          labelSeat.BackColor=Color.Red;
     }
     else if (count==2)
     {
          labelSeat.BackColor=Color.Red;
     }
     else if (count==4)
     {
          count=0;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
private void ColorBox(int elementNumber)
{
    boolean colorRed = ((int)elementNumber/2) % 2 == 0;
    Box[elementNumber].backgroundColor = colorWhite ? "#FF0000" : "#FFFFFF";
}
```

Comment: sorry, i should have phrased my question better, i already have the code to create the boxes im just left with the flow to create the alternating pattern. Thanks for the answer though:D